# Grails: g:link not applying params with dynamic/GString keys

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm trying to create a link with a dynamic link like:

```
<g:link action="${nextDashboardUriMap.nextAction}" params="${["$nextDashboardUriMap.queryStringId": "$entityId" ]}">
        ${entityName}
</g:link>
```

where `nextDashboardUriMap.queryStringId` contains `xyz` and `entityId` contains `12`.

I was expecting url of the link to be `http://website.com/controller/action?xyz=18` but `<g:link/>` consistently gives me `http://website.com/controller/action?xyz`.

I have tried replacing `entityId` with a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it may be this bug: [GRAILS-9774](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9774) - the value is lost if key in params map is of type `GString`. Converting the key to `String` should resolve your problem:

```
<g:link action="${nextDashboardUriMap.nextAction}"
params="${[("$nextDashboardUriMap.queryStringId".toString()): "$entityId" ]}">
(...)
```

Comment: Could you try to restart your app? The old link may be cached.

Comment: I did and it worked! Thanks man! Which link was cached? The one I created with GStrings?

Comment: The one with `GString` key. If the answer was helpful, you can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use GStrings here, you can simply say

```
<g:link action="${nextDashboardUriMap.nextAction}"
        params="[(nextDashboardUriMap.queryStringId):entityId]">
```

Comment: You're right Ian! But I'm still getting the same result :(

Comment: Worked after restarting the app!

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
<%
     Map paramsMap = [:]
     paramsMap[nextDashboardUriMap.queryStringId] = entityId
%>
<g:link action="${nextDashboardUriMap.nextAction}" params="${paramsMap}" >${entityName}
</g:link>
```

Comment: hm, I always thought that you can't use anything dynamic (non static string literal) as a key in map defined this way